# Capturing CTRL+ in keypress event on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events, ctrl

I'm using this code to capture keyboard press events:

```
  $(document.body).keypress(function(e){
    console.log("captured: " + e.which);
  });
```

On Chrome, when a user presses <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, I get the charcode 18.

On Firefox, however, I get 114, in other words just <kbd>r</kbd> without <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

How can I catch the CTRL+ events on Firefox? Preferably, I'd like to just receive the correct charcode without using any translation tables.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check out this plug in from John Resig

[Here is the link](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)

It will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    console.log("captured: " + e.which);
});
```